# Returning strings by reference cpp

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Forgive me if this has been asked before, I am sure it has but I couldn't find an answer I was happy with.

I am coming to cpp from a heavy Java background and would like to understand *when* to return a reference/pointer to an object rather than a copy.

for the following class definition:

```
class SpaceShip {
    string name;
    WeaponSystem weaponSystem; //represents some object, this is just an example, I dont have this type of object at all in my program 
    int hull;

    string GetName() const {
       return name;
    }

    WeaponSystem GetWeaponSystem() const {
       return weaponSystem;
    }

    int GetHull() const {
       return hull;
    }
};
```

I know that returning a copy of things is expensive, I would think this means I want to avoid returning something like a string or weaponSystem by value, but an int by value is ok.

Is this right? I also know that I need to be aware of where things live in memory, does returning a reference to something in this class mean danger down the line if this object is destroyed and something still owns a reference to it's name?

Comment: in general; as long as you don't use a *new* (assigning a location on the heap), you don't need to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: Whilst you could return references here, doing so would violate encapsulation and result in undefined behaviour. Suppose you return a reference to `name` but then destroy the `SpaceShip` instance, you would now have a stale reference to the now destroyed `name`.

Comment: in C++11 returning by-value isn't necessarily a bad choice, and it doesn't necessarily involve copying either.    There are _move semantics_ implemented in C++11 for all of the standard library types (including string, vector, etc).  There are enough subtleties in the C++ language whereby some scenarios exist which allow a "return by value" to be more efficient than a "pass by reference" (due to various quirks involving temporary copies).        However, for simple `get` member-functions, returning by reference-to-const usually makes most sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your last point, you definitely need to be a lot more careful about resource management in C++ than in Java. In particular, you need to decide when an object is no longer needed. Returning by reference has an effect of aliasing to the returned object. It is not noticeable when the object you are sharing is immutable, but unlike Java's Strings, C++ string are mutable. Therefore if you return `name` by value and then rename your `SpaceShip`, the caller would see the old name even after the renaming. If you return by reference, however, the caller will see a change as soon as `ShaceShip` is renamed.

When you deal with copying complex objects, you can decide how much is copied by providing a custom implementation of a copy constructor. If you decide to provide a copy constructor, don't forget [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), and override the other two.

Comment: And if you return by reference and then blow up the space ship, you now have a stale reference to `name`

Comment: @user1937198 Yes, that's the one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It "works" but you should have

```
const string& GetName() const {
```

It may also be beneficial to have the following also

```
const WeaponSystem& GetWeaponSystem() const {
```

Also, `class` is private by default, as such, your accessor functions are private.

Answer (score 0):

the thing you have to know is every getter of your class must be prototype like that :

```
const <type> &className::getXXX() const
{
 ...
}
```

and every setter you make like that :

```
void className::setXXX(const <type> &)
{
 ...
}
```

Use reference when it's possible.
Sometimes, with complex object you can use pointer. That's depend on your code structure.